# How i can fix CORS issue

Tags: php, reactjs, ajax, axios, cors

hello i have try search for a day now on how to solve this problem i have searched both google and axios and youtube but still i can not solve the problem
this is the error on my console when i try to make a call with axios.post

`Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost/prova/test3.php' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Request header field access-control-allow-origin is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response.`

```
AxiosError {message: 'Network Error', name: 'AxiosError', code: 'ERR_NETWORK', config: {…}, request: XMLHttpRequest, …}
code
: 
"ERR_NETWORK"
config
: 
{transitional: {…}, adapter: Array(2), transformRequest: Array(1), transformResponse: Array(1), timeout: 0, …}
message
: 
"Network Error"
name
: 
"AxiosError"
request
: 
XMLHttpRequest {onreadystatechange: null, readyState: 4, timeout: 0, withCredentials: false, upload: XMLHttpRequestUpload, …}
stack
: 
"AxiosError: Network Error\n    at XMLHttpRequest.handleError (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:71536:14)"
[[Prototype]]
: 
Error
```

what i do:

1. tried on my package.json to put proxy: ( my php location) ( http://localhost/) and in the axios post i put (prova/test3.php)

```
  handleSubmit = (event: React.FormEvent<HTMLFormElement>) => {
    event.preventDefault();

    const { username, password } = this.state;

    axios.post('prova/test3.php', { username, password })
      .then(response => {
        console.log(response.data);
        // handle successful login
      })
      
      .catch(error => {
        console.error(error);
        this.setState({ error: 'Invalid username or password' });
      });
  };
```

2. try create an htacess file inside the php project folder with this :

```
RewriteEngine On

Handle Front Controller...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f RewriteRule ^ test3.php [L]
```

3. try on php file :

```
<?php
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET,POST,PUT,OPTIONS");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers:*");

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') {
  $username = $_POST['username'];
  $password = $_POST['password'];
...... some code 
?>
```

Comment: Probably the webserver isn't passing the pre-flight OPTIONS request to PHP. What webserver are you using?

Comment: hey im using XAMMP (Apache HTTP)

Comment: That error message indicates that you're including a header named `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` to your request, which you shouldn't do, since that's a _response_ header. Have you tried dropping that header from your request?

Comment: without this header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET,POST,PUT,OPTIONS");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers:*");  with axios.post(php adress) still give me CORS error...

Comment: @DoggoGigga Ok, but the error message must be different this time. What does it say now?

Comment: has been blocked by CORS policy: Request header field content-type is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response.

Comment: code
: 
"ERR_NETWORK"
config
: 
{transitional: {…}, adapter: Array(2), transformRequest: Array(1), transformResponse: Array(1), timeout: 0, …}
message
: 
"Network Error"
name
: 
"AxiosError"
request
: 
XMLHttpRequest {onreadystatechange: null, readyState: 4, timeout: 0, withCredentials: false, upload: XMLHttpRequestUpload, …}
stack
: 
"AxiosError: Network Error\n    at XMLHttpRequest.handleError (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:71534:14)"
[[Prototype]]
: 
Error

Answer (score 1):

The error message:

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost/artes-backend/test3.php' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Request header field access-control-allow-origin is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response.

suggest that your Javascript (axios call) includes a `access-control-allow-origin` header field, which is not allowed by the server response `Access-Control-Allow-Headers` in the preflight request.

A [pre-flight request](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Preflight_request) is a browser to server request made BEFORE the actual request is sent. In your case, it is an OPTIONS request before your POST request is made.

The pre-flight request is probably something like this:

```http
OPTIONS /artes-backend/test3.php
Access-Control-Request-Method: POST
Access-Control-Request-Headers: origin, x-requested-with
Origin: http://localhost:3000
```

It asks if the origin, the method or the request header fields are accepted by your server.

In response to this request:

1. `header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");` or `header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://localhost:3000");` is needed. Or else there will be CORS issue.
2. `header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: *");` is probably a good idea.
3. `header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET,POST,PUT,OPTIONS");` might not be needed but is probably a good idea.

There can be additional issue with the default Apache / Nginx settings. You need to check the browser console to see the actual request and response header of the pre-flight request to see what actually is happening.

Comment: Request header field access-control-allow-methods is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response. still give this error...

Comment: Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET,HEAD,OPTIONS,POST,PUT
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Content-Type: application/json
Referer: http://localhost:3000/
sec-ch-ua: "Chromium";v="112", "Microsoft Edge";v="112", "Not:A-Brand";v="99"
sec-ch-ua-mobile: ?0
sec-ch-ua-platform: "Windows"
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/112.0.0.0 Safari/537.36 Edg/112.0.1722.64

Comment: @DoggoGigga: Please show the **response** headers of the pre-flight request. The "Networking" tab of browser's developer console is your friend here.

Comment: Also, do you need to add  "Access-Control-Allow-Methods" to your axios request headers?

Comment: In the network page I have two test3.php one in red and one in white the red one has only Request Headers in the page headers, the white one has response headers with this Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Length: 0
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Date: Tue, 02 May 2023 08:26:11 GMT
Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=100
Server: Apache/2.4.56 (Win64) OpenSSL/1.1.1t PHP/8.2.4
X-Powered-By: PHP/8.2.4

Translated with www.DeepL.com/Translator (free version)

Comment: You need to check with request has the "Request Method: OPTIONS" first. The OPTIONS request is the pre-flight request and we're only interested in it. The colour only tell you how the browser things about it.

Comment: Request URL: http://localhost/prova/test3.php
Request Method: OPTIONS
Status Code: 200 OK
Remote Address: [::1]:80
Referrer Policy: strict-origin-when-cross-origin, it has

Comment: Are there any response to the pre-flight request?

Comment: no, i not have preflight request

Comment: The `Request Method: OPTIONS` request you mentioned in the networking tab is the pre-flight request. I was asking if there is any response header to it?

Comment: https://postimg.cc/gallery/qB6Kw04 i put the screenshoot here

Comment: The response of the OPTIONS request (p1) doesn't show any `Access-Control-Allow-Headers` or `Access-Control-Allow-Methods` header. I guess either the script you've shown is not an accurate representation of the real one, or your web server / proxy stack has filtered out those headers.

Comment: const headers  = {
      "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
      "Access-Control-Allow-Headers": "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization"
    }
    axios.post('http://localhost/prova/test3.php', { username, password },{headers})
      .then(response => {
        console.log(response.data);
        // handle successful login
      })
      
      .catch(error => {
        console.error(error);
        this.setState({ error: 'Invalid username or password' });
      });
  };

Comment: the screenshoot i sended use this script i checked now, its the same code without this "Access-Control-Allow-Methods": "GET,HEAD,OPTIONS,POST,PUT",

Comment: By "script" I refers to the `test3.php`. Not the javascript.

Comment: in test3.php i have tthis when i screenshooted header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET,POST,PUT,OPTIONS");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers:*");

Comment: Either these lines are not run or the results are filtered out by your web server / proxy software. For the later case, you need to check with the settings of other software on your server.

Comment: i tried on my macbook using Ampps and its works even without headers... idk what its happening here...

Comment: FIXED cause: for some reasone PHP dont save code....